# Mongo query search updateOne $elemmatch

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble updating my database. I have a surveys collection and each document is as follows:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aaf4f7984521736d88db4bb"
    },
    "title": "4242 ",
    "body": "4242 ",
    "subject": "4242 ",
    "recipients": [
        {
            "email": "a@gmail.com",
            "responded": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab04084be3c1529bcbdcd6e"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": " b@gmail.com",
            "responded": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab04084be3c1529bcbdcd6d"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": " c@gmail.com",
            "responded": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab04084be3c1529bcbdcd6c"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": " d@gmail.com",
            "responded": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab04084be3c1529bcbdcd6b"
            }
        },
        {
            "email": " e@gmail.com",
            "responded": false,
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ab04084be3c1529bcbdcd6a"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_user": {
        "$oid": "5aa5edbf8887a21af8a8db4c"
    },
    "dateSent": {
        "$date": "2018-03-20T00:11:55.943Z"
    },
    "yes": 0,
    "no": 0,
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm calling this on my back-end using mongoose to try and update my database whenever a user responded to a survey.

```
const Survey = mongoose.model('surveys');

Survey.updateOne(
    {
        _id: surveyId,
        recipients: {
            $elemMatch: { email: email, responded: false }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $inc: { [choice]: 1 },
        $set: { 'recipients.$.responded': true }
    }
).exec();
```

But the update is only successful when the query matches the first object in the recipients array. For example, this would work. The query successfully updates the survey document and the recipient subdocument.

```
Survey.updateOne(
    {
        _id: surveyId,
        recipients: {
            $elemMatch: { email: "a@gmail.com", responded: false }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $inc: { [choice]: 1 },
        $set: { 'recipients.$.responded': true }
    }
).exec();
```

But this doesn't work

```
Survey.updateOne(
    {
        _id: surveyId,
        recipients: {
            $elemMatch: { email: "b@gmail.com", responded: false }
        }
    }, 
    {
        $inc: { [choice]: 1 },
        $set: { 'recipients.$.responded': true }
    }
).exec();
```

These are my schemas

```
const surveySchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    subject: String,
    recipients: [RecipientSchema],
    yes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    no: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    dateSent: Date,
    lastResponded: Date
});

const recipientSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    responded: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

When I use node to try to query the database manually, it also only returns the survey when the query matches the first recipient subdocument.

This successfully finds the survey and returns it.

```
Survey.find(
    {   
        _id: "5aaf4f7984521736d88db4bb", 
        recipients: { 
            $elemMatch: {
                email: "a@gmail.com",
                responded: false
            }
    }
}).then(console.log)
```

These don't

```
Survey.find(
    {   
        _id: "5aaf4f7984521736d88db4bb", 
        recipients: { 
            $elemMatch: {
                email: "b@gmail.com",
                responded: false
            }
    }
}).then(console.log)

Survey.find(
    {   
        _id: "5aaf4f7984521736d88db4bb", 
        recipients: { 
            $elemMatch: {
                email: "c@gmail.com",
                responded: false
            }
    }
}).then(console.log)
```

I have been trying to look up how $elemMatch works and someone told me that I can't query the properties of objects inside the recipients array, and that I can only query its IDs.

Comment: is that the full code ?

Comment: There's a lot more but I didn't want to copy my whole route. I just posted what I think is relevant. How does it look? Should I add more?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. The thing you may  be missing is the cast from string to ObjectId for survey id.

Comment: Yeah I think it should work too, that's why I really don't know why it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're storing the subsequent emails without trimming them, as you can see only the first email is properly trimmed, but the rest have a blank space at the beginning , making the query return nothing.